# CSS expand div when content wraps on small screens

Tags: css

The below menu looks ok on standard screens but on small ones the menu items wrap, which is ok, but the containing div #nav does not enlarge. 
I would like the div to automatically enlarge as soon as the items wrap, so the blue bar contains the two (or more) lines of items and the content below is no longer covered

http://www.kine-stammheim.ch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.sf-menu {
    height: 45px; /* remove this line */
    margin: 0px;
    float: right;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Remove the `height` property from the `super.css` file